# cassandra.Client.execute('SOURCE ...') not working

Tags: cassandra, cqlsh, cassandra-driver

133/5000
I want to create my own scylla application where I want to run commands from the file using cassandra-drivers and cqlsh SOURE

[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.0.8 | CQL spec 3.3.1 | Native protocol v4]

docke version
Client:
 Version:           18.09.4
 API version:       1.39
 Go version:        go1.10.8
 Git commit:        d14af54266
 Built:             Wed Mar 27 18:35:52 2019
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          18.09.4
  API version:      1.39 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.10.8
  Git commit:       d14af54
  Built:            Wed Mar 27 18:01:48 2019
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false

```
var cassandra = require('cassandra-driver');

const loadData = () => {
  const client = new cassandra.Client({
    contactPoints: [ 'scylla-node1', 'scylla-node2', 'scylla-node3' ],
    localDataCenter: 'DC1',
    keyspace: 'tracking'
  });

  const query = `SOURCE 'file.txt';`;
  client.execute(query, function(err, result) {
    console.log('TCL: loadData -> result', result);
    if (err) {
      console.log('\n' + err);
    }
  });
...
```

After running code i get error:

```
ResponseError: line 1:0 no viable alternative at input 'SOURCE'
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run CQLSH related commands such as COPY, DESC, SOURCE etc from driver.